# Im using InAppWebView. How to listen url changes and get url?

Tags: flutter

this is my code. I have to navigate my screen. For excemple: if url x.com, navigate to x screen and etc.

```
InAppWebView(
          
  initialUrlRequest:
      URLRequest(url: new Uri.dataFromString(url, mimeType: 'text/html')),
  initialOptions:
      InAppWebViewGroupOptions(crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(),
      ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onUpdateVisitedHistory` property in `InAppWebView` widget

```
InAppWebView(
    key: webViewKey,
    onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
      webViewController = controller;
      _loadHtmlFromAssets();
    },
    onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
      if (url!.host.contains("google.com")) {
        //Prevent that url works
        webViewController?.goBack();
        //You can do anything
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen1()),
        );
      
        return;
      } else if (url.host.contains("yahoo.com")) {
        //You can do anything
        webViewController?.goBack();
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen3()),
        );
        //Prevent that url works
        return;
      } else if (url.host.contains("duckduckgo.com")) {
        //You can do anything
        webViewController?.goBack();
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen2()),
        );
      }
    })
```

here `webcontroller.goback()` used for preventing jump to the site instead of new screen
It may like this:
[image]

**Sample Code:**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  WebViewController? _controller;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
  late PullToRefreshController pullToRefreshController;
  InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      ),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
        useHybridComposition: true,
      ),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      ));

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    pullToRefreshController = PullToRefreshController(
      options: PullToRefreshOptions(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onRefresh: () async {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          webViewController?.reload();
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          webViewController?.loadUrl(
              urlRequest: URLRequest(url: await webViewController?.getUrl()));
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            webViewController?.goBack();
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: InAppWebView(
              key: webViewKey,
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                webViewController = controller;
                _loadHtmlFromAssets();
              },
              onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                if (url!.host.contains("google.com")) {
                  webViewController?.goBack();
                  //You can do anything
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen1()),
                  );
                  //Prevent that url works
                  return;
                } else if (url.host.contains("yahoo.com")) {
                  //You can do anything
                  webViewController?.goBack();
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen3()),
                  );
                  //Prevent that url works
                  return;
                } else if (url.host.contains("duckduckgo.com")) {
                  //You can do anything
                  webViewController?.goBack();
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen2()),
                  );
                }
              }),
        ));
  }

  _loadHtmlFromAssets() {
    var fileText =
        "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title> <style> .rotate { transform: rotate(1700deg) ; } .rotate2 { transform: rotate(90deg) ; } .bg { background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000?image=1069) center/cover; height: 50vh; width: 50vh; } body { margin:0; overflow:hidden; } </style> </head> "
        "<!-- Start your code here --> <ul> <li> <a href ='http://duckduckgo.com/' /><p> duckduckgo.com</a> </li>  <li> <a href='http://www.google.com'>google.com </a> </li>    <li> <a href='http://www.yahoo.com/'> yahoo.com </a> </li></ul> </html>";
    // return Uri.dataFromString(fileText,
    //         mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
    //     .toString();
    webViewController!.loadUrl(
        urlRequest: URLRequest(
            url: new Uri.dataFromString(fileText, mimeType: 'text/html')));

    // _controller?.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileText,
    //         mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
    //     .toString());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Text("Screen 1 google.com"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: MaterialApp(
        home: Container(
          child: Text("Screen 2 yahoo.com"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Text("Screen 3 duck.com"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i used onLoadStop. it worked for me. ty!